# Access 97 / 2002 compatability. Missing Buttons

Tags: ms-access

I have an access 97 mdb which I want to now run using 2002. It all seems to work OK on 2002 but two buttons are missing on a form.  I'm not sure why.

Could you please give me a good starting place, or inforamtion reggarding compatability. I have googled but can't find what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion process can sometimes lead to problems especially if the 97mdb is in a bad state of repair to start with. You could try to....

- Compact and repair the 97mdb and try again.
- Copy the form from the 97mdb and paste it into the 2002mdb
- Try importing all the old objects into a new 97mdb and then trying the conversation tool

When you say the buttons are missing do you mean at design view or when you actually run the form? I had some minor trouble with a few OLE graphs so are they “normal” buttons or activex ones?